# Math in HTML. How do you do simple math with number inputs? And then how do you take results to update your HTML? Is this possible with only HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, database, backend

I am trying to build a simple inventory sheet for renting out items. I am using a table with 3 columns and as many rows as I have for different types of items. The first column is how many are IN STOCK. The second, how many are RENTED. The last Column for an item is a number  I placed inside a . With a submit button. Although I know algorithms and such I am not so experienced in HTML. How and where can I write something to handle a number value from this form to either update the first or second column on this table???

I know that the logic would go something like

```
If(number>0){
   IN STOCK= IN STOCK + number;
   RENTED = RENTED-number;
   If(RENTED< 0){
     IN STOCK = IN STOCK +abs(RENTED);
     RENTED=0;
   }
}
Else if(number<0){
   IN STOCK= IN STOCK - abs(number);
   RENTED = RENTED+abs(number);
   If(IN STOCK < 0){
     IN STOCK = 0;
}
```

See. I even included an edge case. I know that type of coding but I don’t even know how HTML processes these numbers after submit or is using something like abs() is even possible. I’m really lost on this. Does it have to go something with JavaScript, JQuery, or some SQL I don’t know about?JSON EVEN? Need someone to point me in the right direction please

Comment: Consider editing your question to show how the generated result is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

For this project you can be sure that HTML is not enough. As you may know, HTML is a ‘markup language’ (**H**yper **T**ext ***M**arkup **L**anguage*), and it is not made for logic.It is pure description (is it the right word?). So, you need JavaScript (*not* JSON and really *never* SQL, except you need a DB). If you wish, you could use jQuery too. I would use it, because it has many useful methods, but it is your choice.

Comment: HTML is the content.  CSS is the style.  Add them together and you have a description.  The trick to modifying inventory data is: don't do it in the front end.  It needs to be performed on the backend for the updated values to be available for other users.  So when you hit submit, a request is sent to the server, the server processes the request, updates the data store, and sends back a response.  This can involve almost any operating system, programming language, database, or framework.

Comment: This is a possibility too.